# Error after inform password xcode publishing

Tags: ios, xcode

After build app to publish, I click in submit button, and open window to choose Dev Team. I choose user of my client and after show message:

> Your account already has a valid iOS Distribution certificate
>   If you have your signing identity on another Mac, you can import developer profile. You can also revoke the current certificate and request one again

So I click in Import Developer Profile so I choose file identifi (file .developerprofile) and inform password. After click in ok, nothing happens (none error, none message).

Image: http://cl.ly/image/3i0j2r2I3E24

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: It seems that you do not have a valid sigiing entity in place. If this is a distribution certificate created on someother machine, then you u need to export the .cer file and install the same on the machine where you are facing this issue.

Comment: Popeye, my problem is: After click in ok, nothing happens (none error, none message) and no pass to next step

Comment: Thanks  Gajendra, you can explain step by step how install .cer file?